# programming a contest based on cupon codes in drupal

Tags: drupal, registration, draw, invitation

Is there any module that can ask upon user registration so that the user can have a cupon code?
I want to use them later to draw prizes.
Just like a lottery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you give a try to [Registration code](http://drupal.org/project/regcode)? It sounds like it could do the job that you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, I did install that, and it's working :) great module. I guess I have to program a module to draw the winner, and that's that