# Clue on how to program a discount system site like groupon

Tags: drupal, discount, groupon

I found this post: 
[programming a contest based on cupon codes in drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632683/programming-a-contest-based-on-cupon-codes-in-drupal)

I wonder if there is any sort of module that does something like http://www.eversave.com/ or http://www.groupon.com;

Does anybody knows some module(s) that can give me a "head start"?

Maybe a little code clue on how to start?

I really need to make a clone, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the modules search on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org) related to coupons modules. You can go through them and see which one will suit your needs.

http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/coupons?filters=ss_meta_type%3Amodule